# Suggestions on an inequality?

Tags: inequality

I want the following inequality hold:
$$
(\xi_1a_1+\xi_2a_2+\xi_3a_3)(a_4+a_5+a_6) < (a_1+a_2+a_3)(\eta_1a_4+\eta_2a_5+\eta_3a_6)
$$
where $a_1, ..., a_6>0$ and $0 \leq \xi_i < \eta_i$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Is this inequality true or false, and when this inequality can be guaranteed to hold? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily true, as in there are $a_1,\ldots, a_6$ and $\xi_1,\xi_2, \xi_3$ and $\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3$ that meet the conditions of your hypothesis and yet the (strict) inequality $(\xi_1a_1+\xi_2a_2+\xi_3a_3)(a_4+a_5+a_6) > (a_1+a_2+a_3)(\eta_1 a_4+\eta_2 a_5 +\eta_3 a_6)$ holds.

Suppose

1. $a_1=a_4=a_5=a_6 =1$ and $a_2=a_3 = \epsilon$
2. $\xi_1 = (1-\delta)$ for some small $\delta >0$; $\xi_2=\xi_3 = \epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon >0$
3. $\eta_1=1$, $\eta_2=\eta_3= 2\epsilon$.

Then the conditions of your hypothesis are met.

However, $(\xi_1a_1+\xi_2a_2+\xi_3a_3)(a_4+a_5+a_6) \ge 2.75$ if $\delta <.1$

Yet $(a_1+a_2+a_3)(\eta_1 a_4+\eta_2 a_5 +\eta_3 a_6) \le 1.25$ if $\epsilon < .1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$(\xi_1a_1+\xi_2a_2+\xi_3a_3)(a_4+a_5+a_6) < (a_1+a_2+a_3)(\eta_1a_4+\eta_2a_5+\eta_3a_6)$$

$$\iff \frac{(\xi_1a_1+\xi_2a_2+\xi_3a_3)}{(a_1+a_2+a_3)} < \frac{(\eta_1a_4+\eta_2a_5+\eta_3a_6)}{(a_4+a_5+a_6)}\iff \bar \xi<\bar\eta$$

that is a [Weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) which is true in general for $a_1+a_2+a_3=a_4+a_5+a_6$.

To show that let assume

- $\eta_i=\xi_i+d_i \quad d_i>0$

therefore

$$\frac{(\eta_1a_4+\eta_2a_5+\eta_3a_6)}{(a_4+a_5+a_6)}=\frac{(\xi_1a_4+\xi_2a_5+\xi_3a_6)}{(a_4+a_5+a_6)}+\frac{(d_1a_4+d_2a_5+d_3a_6)}{(a_4+a_5+a_6)}=$$

$$=\bar \xi + \bar d>\bar \xi =\frac{(\xi_1a_1+\xi_2a_2+\xi_3a_3)}{(a_1+a_2+a_3)}$$

otherwise in general the inequality is not true and we can find counterexamples as shown also in [Mike answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2904260/505767).

Comment: You seem to have two different values for $\overline{\xi},$ one using $a_4,a_5,a_6$ and one using $a_1,a_2,a_3.$

Comment: I think this solution is wrong because  the mean depend on $a_i$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ops yes of course it is valid for $$a_1+a_2+a_3=a_4+a_5+a_6$$ I fix that. Thanks

Comment: I don't see where $a_1 +a_2+a_3=a_4+a_5+a_6$ is the original question though.

Comment: @Mike Sorry there is still a typo related to the previous version. I fix that. I', not assuming that $a_1 +a_2+a_3=a_4+a_5+a_6$, I'm claiming that the inequality is true, in general, only under that condition.

Comment: @gimusi cool thanks for clearing that up!